# Energetic photon in gravitational potential well

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, gravity, photons, potential

Consider an energetic photon that "climbs out" of a gravitational potential. What happens to the energy of the photon?

a) Does the photon physically lose energy? And is this energy deficit transferred or converted to the gravitational potential energy according to local energy conservation?

b) Is this only an observer related effect: i.e., a distant observer sees a gravitational redshift (based on gravitational time dilation) in his frame of reference?

c) Do both effects occur?

Comment: Energy is not an invariant. It is an observer dependent quantity.

Comment: Hint: if the photon doesn't lose energy you can make a perpetual motion machine that produces unlimited energy.

Answer (score 0):

I think c) is the answer:
a) the photon climbing out of the gravitational potential well loses energy. This is a real physical effect. A good example is the CMB photons in the SW trough.
b) a distant observer (us) in his reference frame sees the photon redshifted, ie with less energy, due to gravitational time dilation. As an example the CMB-SW effect is seen with a gravitational redshift of 10 to -5.

Comment: Where does the energy go when light is redshifted? John Duffield concludes: "It didn't go anywhere. Your and your clocks are now going faster than they were, so you measure the selfsame photon energy as reduced. Even though it hasn't, because conservation of energy applies." I have difficulties to understand. How do you come to this conclusion? Can you please give a more detailed explanation or a mathematical derivation? rhkail@gmx.net